How are you supposed to use C formatting functions safely?
On Linux 64 bit and Windows MinGW a long is most likely 64-bit wide. On Visual Studio 64-bit a long is 32-bit wide. Suppose I have a fixed integer type of 32-bit or 64-bit, when I call something like printf() I have to specify what type is being read. If I get it wrong it's UB. So my either 32 or 64-bit type isn't specifically an int, or a long, or a long long, but typedeffed to God only knows what.
int32_t my_number;

fprintf("%l", my_number); // LONG IS STIPULATED TO BE "AT LEAST" 32-BITS BUT NOT GUARANTEED

int64_t my_number;

fprintf("%ll", my_number); // LONG LONG IS STIPULATED TO BE "AT LEAST" 64-BITS BUT NOT GUARANTEED

The same thing applies to other functions like ltoa(). I guess the problem lies in the fact that from the function's point of view it only knows a 'pointer', and just runs full steam ahead based on which function the programmer called, this seems really crazy error-prone and dangerous, not to mention anything of the fact that if you change one of your types anywhere in your code everywhere that calls these functions makes you computer go boom.

How are you supposed to use these functions given the discrepancy in types and their native sizes?

How are you supposed to deal with the reality that you may change your type somewhere?


Should I even use these functions? Rust people go on about how unsafe C++ is but in comparison to this it's a bubble-wrapped utopian paradise. I usually program C++, would be it better to go through all the types and template the hell out of everything so that each type calls the write function? Would this entail checking something like:
Like this:
template <typename T>
void value_to_ascii(const char* buffer, int max_size, const T& val)
{
     if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, long>)
           ltoa();
     else if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, int>)
           itoa();     
} 


I'll suggest std::format or fmt::print in such case. It should have compile time type check.

"How are you supposed to use these functions..." You aren't.(in modern c++)

In C, you do fprintf("%"PRIi32, my_number); PRIi32 is a macro defined in inttypes.h that expands to a format specifier appropriate for int32_t. There's a whole family of them, for all formats and all integer sizes.

"if you change one of your types anywhere in your code" then you are responsible for making sure the change you've made is properly handled wherever variables of this altered type are used throughout the entire package. What's hard about that?

@Fe2O3 Well with good coding practices you can ensure that if a type changes things won't break, for example using sizeof() instead of hard-coded values. Nearly everywhere I can think of I can go into any of my classes and change a uint64 to a char and things won't change, and I won't have to change anything. Using these functions it's literally impossible to find in a codebase where you need to change it.

The OP needs to pick one language, and not have others alternately narrowing the tags down to C vs C++...

@ikegami As a hi-rep user, you should be aware of the problems that necessitate the caution: ""C is not C++". I've seen a comprehensible Q (that was answered) sent off to oblivion (even after I lightly edited it to "improve its quality"). What's the correct response from a hi-rep user to a badly formed question (that is subject to interpretation by the reader)? The SO guide suggests DV and VTC until the OP makes clear what is being asked. Lots of SO-Meta threads make it clear "answering bad questions is NOT the thing to do." Jus' sayin'....

@Fe2O3, I don't think it's a bad question. Maybe you do, but that's you. It's obviously mistagged, but it seems clear to me. (And as far as I know, my answer accurately describes how to use fprintf in C++ too.)

@Zebrafish After trying to distill out the "rant" portions of your Q, I'm left with 5 different questions about both C and C++ (possibly 6, including the title)... Please edit your post down to one clear question, and select only one of the two language tags.

You don't need to write value_to_ascii, just use std::to_string. All of the problems you talk about are c problems, not c++ problems


How are you supposed to use these functions given the discrepancy in types and their native sizes?

By using the appropriate format.



Type
Format
Notes




long signed int
"%ld"



long long signed int
"%lld"



int32_t
"%" PRId32
#include <inttypes.h>


int64_t
"%" PRId64
#include <inttypes.h>





How are you supposed to deal with the reality that you may change your type somewhere?

You could use the same approach as for int32_t: a typedef, plus a macro for the format.
Whether you do or don't, a worthwhile compiler will warn of mismatches.


How are you supposed to use these functions given the discrepancy in types and their native sizes?


How are you supposed to deal with the reality that you may change your type somewhere

As a first step:
Enable your good compiler's options to look for specifier/type mismatches.
This will catch many easy-to-find errors.
It may miss things like "%lu" matched to a size_t when "%zu" should be used.  size_t and unsigned long may be the same type on your system, but not others.

For something different in C, you can review Formatted print without the need to specify type matching specifiers using _Generic for another approach.
